# Weighted Random number selection

Tags: javascript, random

I'm developing a node.js app where a winner has to be randomly selected based on it's win probability in the range of [0, 100] %

My code is as follows:

```
var activeGame = {
    id: 12324,
    type: 1,
    active: true,
    players: [{
        id: 5032,
        name: "Username",
        foo: true,
        winProbability: 56.32 //%
    }, {
        id: 98243,
        name: "Username",
        foo: true,
        winProbability: 22.68 //%
    }, {
        id: 10943,
        name: "Username",
        foo: false,
        winProbability: 21.00 //%
    }],
};
```

I've found other algorithms that weren't very clear and didn't work with probabilities adding up to 100%.

I'm looking for a way to create a `function selectRandomWinner()` to **return the index of the winning player** but I'm stuck and all and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Generate a single random number 0..100. Compare it to the first player's number. Less? He wins. If greater, then compare to the SUM of the first & second player's numbers. Still greater? Then add the third player's number....etc. In short, just compare your choice to the cumulative sum of the numbers from the players as you go down. The last player will cause the sum to be 100, so he'll win when all others fail (and the right amount).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate a random number from 0 to 100. Then loop through the players adding their probability to a total, until the total is higher than the random number:

```js
var activeGame = {
  id: 12324,
  type: 1,
  active: true,
  players: [{
    id: 5032,
    name: "Joe",
    foo: true,
    winProbability: 56.32 //%
  }, {
    id: 98243,
    name: "Jane",
    foo: true,
    winProbability: 22.68 //%
  }, {
    id: 10943,
    name: "Fred",
    foo: false,
    winProbability: 21.00 //%
  }],
};

function pickPlayer() {
  var randPct = Math.random() * 100;
  var total = 0;
  var players = activeGame.players;
  var selectedPlayer;
  for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    total += players[i].winProbability;
    if (randPct < total) {
      selectedPlayer = players[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  return selectedPlayer;
}

var results = document.getElementById("results");
var resultObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var playerName = pickPlayer().name;
  if (resultObj[playerName]) {
    resultObj[playerName] ++;
  } else {
    resultObj[playerName] = 1;
  }
}
for (name in resultObj) {
  results.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + resultObj[name] + "</td></tr>";
}
```

```html
Results of picking 1000 players:
<table id="results">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Count</th>
</table>
```