# Set the Chance in a Const Array

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a code like this and I want to set some chance according to the names here.

For example "Hades" chances are 79.92% "Mike" 0.26% I want to set it this way but I don't know how to do it.

If I enter a decimal number, I will see an output on the console.
Also, the total chance here is not 100%. Is this a problem?

My Codes:

```js
const users = [
 //79.92% chance after this part
 { name: "Hades", pct: 80 },
 { name: "Mike", pct: 80 },
 { name: "James", pct: 80 },
 { name: "John", pct: 80 },
 { name: "Robert", pct: 80 },
 { name: "Michael", pct: 80 },
 { name: "William", pct: 80 },
 //15.98% chance after this part
 { name: "David", pct: 16 },
 { name: "Richard", pct: 16 },
 { name: "Charles", pct: 16 },
 { name: "Joseph", pct: 16 },
 { name: "Thomas", pct: 16 },
 //3.2% chance after this part
 { name: "Christopher", pct: 4 },
 { name: "Daniel", pct: 4 },
 { name: "Paul", pct: 4 },
 //0.64% chance after this part
 { name: "Mark", pct: 2 },
 { name: "Donald", pct: 2 },
 //0.26% chance after this part
 { name: "Kenneth", pct: 1 },
 { name: "George", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Steven", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Edward", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Brian", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Ronald", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Anthony", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Kevin", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Jason", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Jeff", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Mary", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Patricia", pct: 1 },
 { name: "Linda", pct: 1 },
];

const expanded = users.flatMap((user) => Array(user.pct).fill(user));
const winner = expanded[Math.floor(Math.random() * expanded.length)];
console.log(winner);
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836122/weighted-random-number-selection any help?

Comment: @Thomas No :( sorry

Comment: If, as you state, you actually want "Hades" as well as the other members of  the 80% club, to get *drawn* with an 80% chance, then there's a logical error in you specs. The chances need to add up to 1. For example, as it is, your current code picks elements from the first *bucket* **80 times more likely** than from the last bucket.

Comment: @Yoshi so how should i fix it

Comment: As I said, it's impossible to draw every member of the first group with an 80% chance. So, what you need to do, or the fix, depends on what you want to do instead.